# ASP.NET Core 1.0 - API reference to a .NET 4.5 project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I'm running a solution with project built using .NET 4.5 and now in that same solution I'm adding a ASP Core 1.0 API project that will need to add some of the other projects as reference.

At the moment, I've tried the "Add reference" functionality and wrapping the referenced project on the "project.json" file and the result is still the same. On the github page I've looked on the issues to see if there's something similar but nothing so far.

Is it possible to do this? In a solution with 10 .NET 4.5 other projects (class libraries), add a MVC 6 API project and use the old 4.5 projects as reference in the new on?

Comment: I'm referencing 4.5 projects in my current ASP.NET Core project without issues, so it's definitely possible. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: yes, when adding the references I'm getting the following message "The dependency XXXXX >= 1.0.0.* could not be resolved". Any idea?

My project.json has a net45 area inside frameworks with wrappedproject and bin subelements configured, pointing to the dll to be referenced.

Comment: Which version of .NET 4.5 are the libraries? You might be running into this issue: https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/45 Seems there's an issue referencing 4.5.1 specifically.

Comment: I'm using NET 4.5 Class Library project (not 4.5.1, nor 4.5.2)

Comment: Could you edit your post to include how your project.json looks like, omitting anything sensitive?

Comment: Already found the solution, I need to do a "dnu wrap" on .NET Core project pointing to the dll I want to include. Afterwars just needed to do a "Add Reference" from inside VS2015.2 and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Using command line from inside the folder of the .net core api solution:

```
dnu wrap full_path_to_an_assembly[**\**.dll] -f framework_version [net45]
```

Inside Visual Studio, "Add Reference" -> select your .NET 4.5 Project and it works.

No need to add wrappedprojects section to project.json.